# Namespace '<global namespace>' already contains a definition for 'PlayerCollision'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Error:

> Assets\Scripts\PlayerCollision.cs(4,14): error CS0101: The namespace '' already contains a definition for 'PlayerCollision'

```
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerCollision : MonoBehaviour {

    void OnCollisionEnter (Collision collisionInfo)
    {
        if (collisionInfo.collider.tag == "Obstacle")
        {
            Debug.Log("We hit something");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like there already is another type with the same name ...

Answer (score 1):

You cannot name the `MonoBehaviour` script the same as an internal name(PlayerCollision).

Try a prefix like My:

```
public class MyPlayerCollision : MonoBehaviour {
```

Comment: `PlayerCollision` isn't anything Unity built-in though, and if it was it would sit in the namespace `UnityEngine` ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can put your `PlayerCollision` in a namespace of its own (and to avoid other namespace issues, do the same for other classes in your project):

```cs
using UnityEngine;

namespace MyGame
{
    public class PlayerCollision : MonoBehaviour {
        //your code here
    }
}
```